# How to get Retrofit/OkHttp to support TLSv1.2 only on all phones (Android >= 5)

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, tls1.2, okhttp

I am using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for REST API calls in my Android application, and I have chosen to support only Android 5.0 and newer.

Because TLSv1.2 is supported by those Android versions, I set up my server to only use TLSv1.2. When I test on Nexus 5x (Android versions 7.1 and 8.0) and Nexus 5 (Android version 6.0), everything works as expected. However, when I test on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, the app is unable to connect to the server unless I enable TLSv1.1.

I know that the S6 Edge supports TLSv1.2 because when I make an HTTPS connection using `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` and manually setting the TLS version to 1.2 (using `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")`, etc.), it works as expected.

I looked through the OkHttp code (that Retrofit uses to actually make the API calls) and I can't find where it chooses what version to use.

Why does only the Samsung device not default to using TLSv1.2 in Retrofit/OkHttp and how can I force it to do so?

---

NOTE: This question is *not* asking how to enable TLSv1.2 support in older Android versions, which has been answered many times on StackOverflow. It is just asking why this works by default on some Android 6.0 phones and not others.

Comment: The general approach OkHttp uses is covered [in the wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS). In terms of forcing it, try `new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS).tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)` as part of setting up an `OkHttpClient` that you use explicitly with Retrofit.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I still want to know why the same Android version running on different hardware uses different versions by default.

Comment: My guess is that if you try forcing it, you will get some sort of error that will help clarify the situation.